# Ajax.BeginForm in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

The issue i am facing has taken more then 8 hours but couldn't find the solution to it.
I am trying to implement ajax functionality in MVC4.
I've following code in index view.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
        new AjaxOptions
        {

            HttpMethod = "get",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "resturantList"
        }
    ))
{ 
    <input type="search" name="searchTerm" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search By Name" />
}

<div id="resturantList">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    { 
        <div>
            <h4>@item.Name</h4>
            <div>@item.City, @item.Country</div>
            <div>Reviews: @item.CountOfReviews</div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

---

Following is html which renders when search button is clicked.

[image: "screenshot of application"]

---

I've checked the script files references by firebug even they are included

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js">
```

Tried to remove the

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

from web.config file which solves the above stated issue but it also disables the client side validations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not telling the form to post the data on which action of which controller, this is causing the problem,do like this, pass controller and action name as well:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
"Action", "Controller",
        new AjaxOptions
        {

            HttpMethod = "get",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "resturantList"
        }
    ))
{ 
    <input type="search" name="searchTerm" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search By Name" />
}

<div id="resturantList">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    { 
        <div>
            <h4>@item.Name</h4>
            <div>@item.City, @item.Country</div>
            <div>Reviews: @item.CountOfReviews</div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

and second thing,make sure you are returning a partial view,if full view is returing that will also cause issues.Do this in you view for it:

```
@{

Layout = null

}
```

Actually you have to return partial view in the response of ajax call